# How to change Google Sheet to "Viewing" while having "Editing" access?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

For Gdocs, Edit access can be changed to Viewing to avoid unwanted changes.

[image]

How can that be done for Gsheets?

Comment: It seems like Gsheets should have this feature which Gdocs already has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no button in the UI for it, but there is a "Preview" mode available for Google sheets. To get to it you need to edit the URL.

The URL of a sheet in normal editing mode ends with something like `...sOmE-lOnG-ID/edit#gid=1234567`. Remove the `/edit` and everything after it, and replace it with `/preview`. Hit enter to refresh the page.

It will load a data-only view, no toolbars or anything. Useful to avoid making any changes, though unfortunately there's no commenting feature like Docs has.

Comment: The /preview option does disable edits, but it also disables the selection of the Gsheet data. I'd like to be able to disable edits while still being able to copy the displayed data.

Comment: Aha, that would be a downside. The only other way I can think to get view-only access would be to change the sharing settings to "Anyone with the link can view", then visit the share URL from a private/incognito window.

If the data's too sensitive to allow even a chance that the URL might get shared somewhere, then you could share it with another Google account you can use, and give it view-only access. Same result, more steps.

Comment: Another thought: there are "protected ranges" in Google Sheets, which block users from editing *parts* of a sheet. It's not a document-level setting, and it's not something you can toggle on and off, but it could be helpful: https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308980?hl=en